# What JSON would be valid for keyword 'anyOf'

Tags: json, jsonschema

I was wondering if someone could give an example of JSON that would be valid for a schema using the 'anyOf' keyword? I'm trying to write some code that will output valid JSON in python.

For example, if you had a schema that looked like this:

```
"anyOf": {
       "category_0": {
                "main": { "enum": ["learning"]},
                "sub":  { "enum": ["ADD/ADHD", "dyslexia", "general learning disability", "language disorder", "intellectual giftedness", "other"]}
                         },
       "category_1": {
                "main": { "enum": ["mental"]},
                "sub":  { "enum": ["down's syndrome", "asperger's syndrome", "autism", "other"]}
                 },
       "category_2": {
                "main": { "enum": ["behavioral"]}
                 },
       "category_3": {
                "main": { "enum": ["medical"]},
                "sub":  { "enum": ["diabetes", "allergies", "eating disorders", "chronic illness", "other"]}
                 },
       "category_4": {
                "main": { "enum": ["physical"]},
                "sub":  { "enum": ["blind", "deaf", "cerebral palsy", "other"]}
                    }
                 }
```

what JSON would be valid?

The code I've used to output JSON in python is this:

```
main = row.get('main', [])
sub = row.get('sub',[])
category = dict(main = main, sub=sub)
special_needs = category
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, the code you posted is json

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @user814628 The posted code isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON isn't valid because strings can't be outside the outermost array or object.

Minimally valid JSON looks like this: `{}`.  You can make your JSON valid by putting what you've shown here inside of that:

```
{
  "anyOf": {
    "category_0": {
      "main": {
        "enum": [
          "learning"
        ]
      },
      "sub": {
        "enum": [
          "ADD/ADHD",
          "dyslexia",
          "general learning disability",
          "language disorder",
          "intellectual giftedness",
          "other"
        ]
      }
    },
    "category_1": {
      "main": {
        "enum": [
          "mental"
        ]
      },
      "sub": {
        "enum": [
          "down's syndrome",
          "asperger's syndrome",
          "autism",
          "other"
        ]
      }
    },
    "category_2": {
      "main": {
        "enum": [
          "behavioral"
        ]
      }
    },
    "category_3": {
      "main": {
        "enum": [
          "medical"
        ]
      },
      "sub": {
        "enum": [
          "diabetes",
          "allergies",
          "eating disorders",
          "chronic illness",
          "other"
        ]
      }
    },
    "category_4": {
      "main": {
        "enum": [
          "physical"
        ]
      },
      "sub": {
        "enum": [
          "blind",
          "deaf",
          "cerebral palsy",
          "other"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sure wrapping by {} or [] is mandatory for valid JSON format ! that is why you always have a *one* entry point for json datas, and access it like myDecodedJsonObj.anyOf